# Can I run the Ubuntu SDK for Windows?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, windows-8, ubuntu-sdk

The last question on this was 2 years ago, so I'm hoping that things have changed...

I spend a lot of time in college, and use the Windows PCs there. I would really like to begin development for Ubuntu Touch; I would use a live USB, but unfortunately there is BIOS protection on the PCs **:(**

**Question:** Is it possible to run the Ubuntu SDK on Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

Use VMware or [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to run a Linux system on Windows is a very good solution for you.

Comment: hmm... If I have a powerful enough PC

Comment: What is your PC spec?

Comment: Core i3 - 4GB RAM